# Program to print all combinations of numbers whose square equal to given number

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printCombs(int n) {
    int i, j, limit = ceil(sqrt(n));
    for(i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
        for(j = i; j < limit; j++) {
            if(i*i + j*j == n) {
                printf("%d,%d\n", i, j);
                printf("%d,", j);
                printCombs(i*i);
                printf("\n%d,", i);
                printCombs(j*j);    
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printCombs(n);

    return 0;
}
```

I have written this code which outputs combinations of numbers whose sum of squares equals the given input. The code is working fine but the problem is with the not-wanted output.

For example I enter 1000:

```
1000
10,30
30,6,8
8,
6,

10,18,24
24,
18,

18,26
26,
18,10,24
24,6,8
8,
6,

10,
```

First I get 10,30 which is fine because 100+900 = 1000.

Then 30, 6, 8 => 900+36+64 = 1000.

Then 10, 18, 24 => 100 + 324 + 576 = 1000.

Then 18, 26 => 324 + 676 = 1000.

Then 18, 10, 24 => 576 + 100 + 324 = 1000.

Now these are all the combinations. But as you can see there are some other number output also on the screen which are due to the `printf()` before the recursive calls which do not output anything. And in the end when it outputs `24, 6, 8`.`. I am not being able to figure out how to prevent this from output-ing. How do I just print those combinations? Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: passing "prefix" to your function seems the simpler.(to get rid of `printf("%d,", j);`, you would need `sprintf`).

Comment: @Jarod42 i dont get it?

Comment: But your algo can miss some combination: `3 = 1²+1²+1²` but cannot be written as `a²+b²`...

Comment: @Jarod42 I know its not the question but only if you can guide me to a more general approach to this problem? I mean, I know that this can be done by applying nested loops so that every combination can be checked but how do I convert that into recursion?

Comment: I meant something like [that](https://ideone.com/bCbUMN)

Comment: I [broke your function in two](https://ideone.com/wjd59G) ([old code](https://ideone.com/tTzUOi)), so that printing happens only when I want (when I have two or three valid numbers).

Comment: @RumaisaTahir, I am still confused by the algorithm.  The key to writing a good recursive function is getting the exit conditions correct.  If you are using a for loop, you may be avoiding a simpler recursive solution.   Are these the rules:

Comment: 1. Find all combinations of squares that add up to the input number.  2. Squares may include "1".    3. Squares may be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than printing little by little, try and print all numbers in one statement.

For that you may need to rewrite your function a little bit.

Here's my attempt

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void printCombs2(int n, int k) {
    int limit = ceil(sqrt(n));
    for (int i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < limit; j++) {
            if (i*i + j*j == n) {
//                printf("%d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k);
                printf("%d, %d, %d ==> %d+%d+%d=%d\n", i, j, k, i*i, j*j, k*k, i*i+j*j+k*k);
            }
        }
    }
}

void printCombs(int n) {
    printf("combs(%d):\n", n);
    int limit = ceil(sqrt(n));
    for (int i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < limit; j++) {
            if (i*i + j*j == n) {
//                printf("%d, %d\n", i, j);
                printf("%d, %d ==> %d+%d=%d\n", i, j, i*i, j*j, i*i+j*j);
                printCombs2(i*i, j);
                printCombs2(j*j, i);
            }
        }
    }
    puts("");
}

int main(void) {
    printCombs(100);
    printCombs(1000);
    printCombs(10000);

    return 0;
}
```

see it [running on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/wjd59G)

```
combs(100):
6, 8 ==> 36+64=100

combs(1000):
10, 30 ==> 100+900=1000
6, 8, 30 ==> 36+64+900=1000
18, 24, 10 ==> 324+576+100=1000
18, 26 ==> 324+676=1000
10, 24, 18 ==> 100+576+324=1000

combs(10000):
28, 96 ==> 784+9216=10000
60, 80 ==> 3600+6400=10000
36, 48, 80 ==> 1296+2304+6400=10000
48, 64, 60 ==> 2304+4096+3600=10000
```

Comment: isnt Jarod's solution more neat?

Comment: You may prefer it. It finds more answers (answers with 4 numbers) than your solution (so it's not really the same). I find my version easier to understand because there is no *prefix* to keep track of. If you need a recursive solution, then **yes**, Jarod's solution is definitively better.